# WPF: DataGrid text getting cut by the underneath row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

As you can seen in given below image the text and image is getting cut. Also, you can see that there are some space left above the text that we can use. How can we shift the text a bit upside so that it will not get cut.

I am quite new to WPF, please be lenient towards me.

Given below is the datagird xaml:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Margin="30" Name="scanStatusGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="50" GridLinesVisibility="None">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#626464" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/TechHeal.Presentation.UINEW;component/Fonts/#Open Sans"/>

                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
                </Style>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e3f4f8"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                    </Style>

            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="200">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding imagestat}"  Height="20" Width="20"/>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Issue" Width="200" Binding="{Binding errorCount}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Scan Items" Width="*" Binding="{Binding scanName}">

                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: You have set the height of row as 25 and cell to 25. When row adds cell it adds padding to its child; that's why cell is not being displayed as you require. Change the height of Row. Also override the default padding for cell and row

Comment: @Hardik Sachdeva why you are using Row height ? Remove it altogether and see.

Comment: thanks @user1672994 and @ \AnjumSKan